# With ThreadPoolExecutor, what is the difference between allowCoreThreadTimeOut and zero core threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Reading up on the documentation of [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), I'm confused what the difference is between the following to example usages:

Zero core threads and ten max threads, of which the latter times out after 2 seconds:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        0, // core threads
        10, // max threads
        2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
        Executors.defaultThreadFactory()
);
```

Ten core threads and ten max threads that both time out after 2 seconds:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        10, // core threads
        10, // max threads
        2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
        Executors.defaultThreadFactory()
);

executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

Do these executors behave differently in any way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the motivation [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6233235).

> I want something like fixed thread pool
>   (Executors.newFixedThreadPool()) but with threads dying off when they
>   are idle for too long, and re-created when they are needed again.
>
> The most intuitive approach - set core size to 0, maximum pool size to
>   the bounding value, and the queue to [an unbounded queue]
>   - fails: no tasks get executed at all (consistently with Javadoc but - IMHO - a little bit counterintuitively).

`executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);` can be used to get this behavior.

**More details why no tasks get executed at all if `corePoolSize = 0` is specified**

From the Javadoc,

> Using an unbounded queue (for example a LinkedBlockingQueue without a
>   predefined capacity) will cause new tasks to wait in the queue when
>   all corePoolSize threads are busy. Thus, no more than corePoolSize
>   threads will ever be created. (And the value of the maximumPoolSize
>   therefore doesn't have any effect.)

Hence, if you specify `corePoolSize = 0` no threads will ever be created, and no tasks will be executed at all.

**In practice, however,** when the corePoolSize is zero, implementations does create one thread (tested with Sun JDK6 and OpenJDK11). So in practice, the tasks *are* executed, but no more than one thread is ever created, regardless of what `maximumPoolSize` is specified. I'm not entirely sure why because according to the spec, it shouldn't create even one.

Below is my test code. This will only ever use one thread, but if you specify `corePoolSize=10`, it will use 10. If you add `allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)`, then these threads can timeout.

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        0, // core threads
        10, // max threads
        2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        q
);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    executor.execute(() ->
        {
           try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           System.out.println(
               "TaskNo:" + j + ":" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
           );
         });
}

executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: From that link: "The most
intuitive approach - set core size to 0, maximum pool size to the
bounding value, and the queue to some kind of LinkedQueue or ArrayQueue
- fails: no tasks get executed at all (consistently with Javadoc)." Can you please elaborate on why nothing would get executed in example 1?

Comment: Added more details @BennyBottema

Comment: So even with core threads at 0 and max threads 10, it will not create any threads?

Comment: The implementation (Sun JDK6 and Open JDK11) puzzlingly creates exactly one thread at core threads = 0, max threads = 10. I'm not sure why because according to the spec it shouldn't create any threads. Try my test code to see for your self! @BennyBottema

Answer (score 0):

With coreSize=0, only one thread is used to execute tasks until the queue is full. (This is the behavir of Java 1.6+. With Java 1.5, no tasks will be executed before the queue is full. see [ThreadPoolExecutor with corePoolSize 0 should not execute tasks until task queue is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253164/threadpoolexecutor-with-corepoolsize-0-should-not-execute-tasks-until-task-queue))

With coreSize=n and allowCoreThreadTimeOut=true, up to n threads will be created to execute tasks until the queue is used.